# Weblogic JMS queue and differences between production, consumption, and insertion

Tags: queue, jms, weblogic

I want a Weblogic queue to receive a message, but I don't want to process that message further. I want the messages I've sent to the queue to stay there before they are consumed.

So I think I need to pause Production and Consumption but leave Insertion to run so every message sent to that Queue will stay there, and I will be able to read each message created there. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean you want the messages to "stay there before they are consumed"? Where are they going to go?

Comment: They can be consumed by someone who read from that Queue, or it could be redirected to other queue(s). So it will be no there any more and I will lost that messages and I want to see them exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Weblogic documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/JMSAD/troubleshoot.htm#i1127352) on this subject you should *only* pause consumption. If you pause production then producers will not be able to send messages to the queue. As the documentation states:

> When a JMS destination is "paused for production," **new and existing producers attached to that destination are unable to produce new messages** for that destination. A producer that attempts to send a message to a paused destination receives an exception that indicates that the destination is paused.

Also, if you pause insertion then any in-flight messages will not appear on the queue either. Again, from the documentation:

> When a JMS destination is paused for "insertion," both messages inserted as a result of in-flight work and new messages sent by producers are prevented from appearing on the destination. **Use insertion pause to stop all messages from appearing on a destination.**

That said, if consumption is paused then *you* won't be able to consume the messages either, although you should be able to use a JMS browser to inspect them.

Comment: what does it means "in-flight" work? so, if I want to send message to Queue, but I don't want anyone to let any application to read this message because I want to check something in WL JMS browser and I want that messages to be there for me, I need to pause production, right? but, this will not stop any "inside" messages, only messages from producer. So, if I want to stop all messages, from producer, but as some inside process, I need to pause only INSERTION, right?

Comment: And can you help me with this also, pls?
I want to do the same with SAF, that SAF receives a message but not forward anywhere. So I need to pause forwarding, right? Thank You 
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/saf_agents/MonitorSAFAgentRemoteEndpoints.html

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/JMSAD/troubleshoot.htm#i1127457) for more details on "in-flight" messages. If you don't want any application to *consume* the messages (i.e. leave the message there for you) then you want to pause **consumption**, not production. If you pause production then producers won't be able to send new messages.

Comment: You should ask a *new* question about the SAF use-case since it's different from your original question.